# Storing UUID in MySQL considering query performance

Tags: mysql, database

We are working on designing a table's column in MySQL which is intended to store a binary(16) data generated using `newid()` function in SQL Server (e.g. `0xA6D42A825114472FAF402180E20B3751`).

This data is present in our application as a java String like `A6D42A825114472FAF402180E20B3751` .

Our main use case is to query the table in MySQL on this column based on the String value in our app. What would be the most efficient way to store it in MySQL if we consider query performance ? (We figured out that space wise using binary(16) should be the most efficient way)

Comment: Why not use an index for this? If the UUID is generated randomly, this might be the simplest idea - or do you have anything else in mind with the broad term "efficient way"?

Comment: so querying on a binary column is no way considered a non-performant query right ? we can use binary(16) column and have an index on it. that would be better then having a char/varchar and querying on those columns right ?